# Как добавить класс родительскому элементу, а у других удалить?

Tags: javascript

друзья! Есть следующая разметка и js код. При клике по ссылке родительскому блоку .item добавляется класс .new-class. Как сделать чтобы при клике по ссылке у всех блоков класс .new-class удалялся если он есть, а родительскому добавлялся?

```js
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for (let i of item) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('item-link')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.classList.add('new-class');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container .new-class {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
    <a href="#" class="item-link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Cupiditate iste mollitia ipsum. Repellat, numquam facere!</p>
    <a href="#" class="item-link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Nobis unde deserunt ut delectus, amet, ducimus.</p>
    <a href="#" class="item-link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for (let i of item) {
    i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('item-link')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        for (let i of item) {
          if (i != this)
             i.classList.remove('new-class');
        }
        this.classList.add('new-class');
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container .item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 15px;
}
.container .new-class {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
    <a href="#" class="item-link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Cupiditate iste mollitia ipsum. Repellat, numquam facere!</p>
    <a href="#" class="item-link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Nobis unde deserunt ut delectus, amet, ducimus.</p>
    <a href="#" class="item-link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```